# Node.js & MongoDB performance issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having some weird performance issues with MongoDB. First I tried to get about ~1000 documents through the [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs) driver which did work, but finished the query in about 60+ seconds. Note that the documents are not big in any way!

Then I tried to do the same query but ran an explain() against the mongo shell to check if it really was just the query being so slow. Upon inspection it turned out that the query took only 4ms to complete! I have no idea what's causing this. Any ideas?

Some more details:

- Small documents
- The MongoDB server is located on another server which I'm connected to through VPN
- Indexes are placed where necessary

**EDIT:**

I ran wireshark and noticed the following:

1. The query gets send to the server
2. The server responds with 101 documents in under 1ms (always the same number)
3. The client does a "Get More" request
4. It takes about a minute or two before the server responds with the rest of the documents
5. The "Get More" request and server responses with documents continues until it has sent everything. Which might take... forever for even the smallest set of around 1000 documents!

Here's a piece of code that I run in the node CLI:

```
/* Get all the documents (about 1000) */
var db = require('mongojs').connect("myIpAddress", ["myCollection"]);
db.myCollection.find({}).forEach(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm not sure whether it's related but every now and then I get a "TCP Out of Order" packet from wireshark.

**EDIT 3:**

I tried to adjust the batch size, this did not work. I also tried [MongoSkin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) to make sure it wasn't [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs) doing something wrong, but that didn't solve anything as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by copying the MongoDB server to the same place where my Node server was running. I think it had to do with the VPN I was connected to, although I can't say that with certainty.

Comment: Glad you figured out a work around. Still curious about what the issue with the remote DB was.

Comment: I had to connect to the VPN through some piece of Cisco software which I'm guessing was the problem. Once I managed to set up the VPN connection manually (through the Windows interface) it just started working!

Answer (score 1):

Some other ideas:

1. Mongoose works pretty well IMO, can you replace Mongojs with Mongoose?
2. Play with the parameters of the find query and chain a .batch_size() with a high value.
3. Run Wireshark and monitor the connection and see which interaction is waiting 60 seconds. Might be some peculiar Nodejs - VPN network interaction issue.

Could you post your code?

...edit - try this (havent tested it so might have some syntax quirks - check with your program)

```
/* Get all the documents (about 1000) */
var db = require('mongojs').connect("myIpAddress", ["myCollection"]);
db.myCollection.find({}).forEach(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
}).batch_size(2000);
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't help a bit. I also tried it with MongoSkin (a different library) but it didn't matter, the same problem occurs.

Comment: What happens if you try the code from Sachin's answer, but put the batch_size call before the forEach?

Comment: I tried this as well but it didn't matter. See my own answer for more information, and thanks for the help! :)